# In the Command pattern what do you call a command that groups together other commands?

Tags: design-patterns, naming-conventions, command-pattern

This should be easy,

I am trying to come up with the name for a command class that is a collection of other commands.   All the sub commands will be run, when the master command is run.

Any ideals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)Command, maybe?

Comment: thanks, that what I thought of, but I wished to check if other people use the name in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Composite Command?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth,
the *Head First* book from O'Reilly about design patterns calls it a
[MacroCommand](http://books.google.com/books?id=GGpXN9SMELMC&lpg=PA227&ots=IoG7HOS2L0&dq=head%20first%20design%20pattern%20macro%20command&pg=PA227#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

"Batch Command" would be my choice.

Comment: Not a bad choice actually; however, I personally would associate a "batch command" with a specific use case, namely _applying_ a fixed sequence of commands _to a set of input items_. I find "composite command" more neutral in its meaning.

Comment: For us this would not work, as our software tracks "batches" in pipelines.   However I like this name as Composite is harder for poeple that don't have English has a first language.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply creating a base class that will automatically execute a list of commands, and is meant to be used as is (i.e. just create a generic Command and pass in a list of sub commands) then I'd use something like CompositeCommand or BatchCommand.  If this is not meant to be a generic class but rather a hard-coded specific implementation I'd name it after what the overall operation is.  For example:

```
BatchCommand registerCmd = new BatchCommand();
registerCmd.add(new CreateProfileCmd());
registerCmd.add(new CreatePreferences());
registerCmd.add(new SendWelcomeEmailCmd());
```

vs

```
class RegisterCmd extends Command {
  execute() {
    new CreateProfileCmd().execute();
    new CreatePreferences().execute();
    new SendWelcomeEmailCmd().execute();
  }
}
```

In the second case I wouldn't create a new name for the RegisterCmd class.  It's just a command that happens to call other commands to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

I liked BatchCommand, it represents what it is. I think that CompositeCommand is very "pattern", just as prefixing with "Singleton" a class that is supposed to have only one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Could use "Script" as another alternative suffix (but I'd probably go with CompositeCommand)